# SQL Server Position of an element in table with different order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am using a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014 to get the position of an item.

I've read about ROW_NUMBER but I am not sure how to use it (or if I can use it at all).

I have a table containing elements with IDs and dates and I would like to know the position of an element given its ID in the table sorted by date.

Let's say for instance I have these 5 items (ID. Date) :

```
ID        DATE  
1      2016-01-04  
2      2016-01-05  
3      2016-01-01  
4      2016-01-02  
5      2016-01-03
```

Using my stored procedure to get the position of 3., I want it to return 5 (the actual position of 3. when the table is ordered by date desc).

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` if you want only one result if there are duplicates, or `RANK` if you want every row that fits with your criteria (for instance, if there is more than 1 row with `2016-01-03` value):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT ID, [Date]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 3;
```